# Is a metric space a requirements for the application of the algebra of events from probability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, metric-spaces

When I refer to a metric space, I mean a space that has some genuine notion of distance. In some applied context, this distance would be computed with respect to a coordinate system. I just wanted to know whether a notion of distance is required for the application of the Algebra of Events -- from probability theory. I imagine this is particularly true in the sense of continuous random variables. If I remember my real analysis then I believe the space has to be metric, but I as not sure.

Just some background on why I am asking. I work on social science data, and in many cases the data seems to lack a genuine notion of distance, but often some arbitrary distance metric is applied to make things fit. For example, there are indices on how "democratic" or "authoritarian" as political regime is. The indices are based upon some standards of the fairness of elections, the ability for the government and leaders to be replaced peacefully, etc. BUT, the notion that a regime that is marked as a 2 and a regime that is marked as a 5 are 3 units in democracy apart seems rather imprecise or arbitrary (scale: where 1 is democratic and 10 is authoritarian). So if this notion of distance in this case is so arbitrary, then running a regression on the probability of a regime being a 2, 3, 4.5, or 5 seems like it is not at all workable. In that case, probability and statistics should not be applied against numbers that don't have a meaningful coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a metric space for "the application of the Algebra of Events"--as your nomenclature suggests, all you need is something like an algebra, technically a $\sigma-algebra$ in most models. Assigning (possibly arbitrary) notion of distance to a random variable for the purposes of regression is separate from the ability to ask questions about the events that RV assumes.